# CPP Exception handler not called for exceptions during mutex lock

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, crash-dumps, msvcrt

We had a code that created a deadlock as below (simplified version)

```
std::shared_timed_mutex read_file_mutex;
std::shared_lock<std::shared_timed_mutex> read_file_lock(read_file_mutex
    , std::defer_lock);
if (read_file_lock.try_lock_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(200))) {
  ...
  ...
  if (read_file_lock.try_lock_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(200))) {
```

The second try_lock throws an exception as expected for resource deadlock from MSVC shared_mutex during validation:

```
void _Validate() const {
  // check if the mutex can be locked
  if (!_Pmtx)
    _THROW(system_error(
        _STD make_error_code(errc::operation_not_permitted)));
  if (_Owns)
    _THROW(system_error(
        _STD make_error_code(errc::resource_deadlock_would_occur)));
}
```

Question is when above exception is raised why is it invoking watson handler with invalid parameter exception when we have registered our own invalid parameter exception handler? This is causing the program to terminate without generating crash dump.

We have exception handlers set for UnhandledExceptionFilter, _set_invalid_parameter_handler, _set_purecall_handler, Abort Signal handler etc as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13591334/what-actions-do-i-need-to-take-to-get-a-crash-dump-in-all-error-scenarios) All other types of exceptions are calling our handlers fine, where we signal a secondary process to generate crash dump. Invalid parameter exception as given in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/set-invalid-parameter-handler-set-thread-local-invalid-parameter-handler?view=msvc-170&redirectedfrom=MSDN) example also calls our handler just fine.

```
_invalid_parameter_handler old_handler, new_handler;

SetUnhandledExceptionFilter(&UnhandledExceptionHandler);
new_handler = HandleInvalidParameter;
old_handler = _set_invalid_parameter_handler(new_handler);
_set_purecall_handler(PureVirtualCallHandler);

void (*rv)(int) = signal(SIGABRT, HandleAbortSignal);
_set_abort_behavior(0, 0);
EnableCrashingOnCrashes();
PreventSetUnhandledExceptionFilter();
```

What is so special about exception from shared_timed_mutex or system_error exceptions? What needs to be done to register the handler for this properly?

Software is 32bit running on 64 bit Windows 10. Compiler used is clang

Comment: “try_lock throws an exception as expected for resource deadlock”. Wrong. Locking or try locking a mutex on the same thread twice is undefined behaviour and anything can happen.

Comment: Would that be a valid enough reason to not call exception handler? we could change the   procedure for mutex locking to fix this particular issue but wondering if there are more such issues where we cannot rely on exception handlers to get crash dump

Comment: If you want defined behavior and you have a situation that a thread can try to lock a mutex, then use std::recursive_mutex but best is to avoid that situation by design (not always possible).

Comment: We would have to lock the mutex for a thread only once and can enforce this easily. Calling twice was really a bug.

Comment: Where is the code that eventually throws the C++ exception being called from? The system sets up exception filters around callbacks (such as a window procedure), and maybe there is *some* unintended interaction. A [mcve] would help for additional context.

Comment: It turns out disabling cpp exceptions on some applications (which has mix of C/CPP code) causes mixed behaviors in included cpp libraries with exceptions usage. SOME types of exceptions in these libraries call registered exception handlers properly but some other types of exceptions like system_error do not call registered handlers but invoke watson directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out disabling cpp exceptions on some applications (which has mix of C/CPP code) causes mixed behaviors in included cpp libraries using exceptions. SOME types of exceptions in these libraries call registered exception handlers properly but some other types of exceptions like system_error do not call registered handlers but invoke watson directly

Comment: I'm glad you have got your solution and thank for your sharing. I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.